# jQuery Code to change text depending on class of slide

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the text color of the navigation depending if the first slide has the class `"flex-active-slide"`, you can see the nav here [www.zadroinc.com](https://zadroinc.com/).

I'm using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 if ($(".slide").eq(0).hasClass("flex-active-slide")) {
   $(".z-nav > li > a").css("color", "white"); 
 } else { 
   $(".slide").eq(1).hasClass("flex-active-slide");
   $(".z-nav > li > a").css("color", "black"); }
});
```

What I'm running into is that it changes the color, but it won't do it again when the slide changes.

Comment: are you running the fn() for all the click events on `$(".slide")`, if not you will not have the logic executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is only running once when the document is ready, whatever event or timing driven code you have running to change the slides on your site would be the best place to incorporate your function to change the css of your nav anchor elements.

If for some reason you can't incorporate the code to change your css into the script that is already running to change your slides, then you can try triggering the css changes based on the css transitions that are happening on the anchor links in your "slide" classed li elements.

```
$('.slide a').on('transitionend', function() {
  // get index of transitioned anchor element's parent slide
  var slideIndex = $(this).parent().index();
  if (slideIndex === 0) {
    $('.z-nav > li > a').css('color', 'white');
  } else {
    $('.z-nav > li > a').css('color', 'black');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your CSS to get this done. Based on the slider you are using, you need to change the background color instead.

```
.slide-show-render.slide-show .flex-control-nav.flex-control-paging li:first-of-type a.flex-active {background:#fff}
```